# Does AWS API G/w support MTLS with Websockets?

Tags: websocket, mtls, aws-api-gateway-v2

Wondering if AWS API G/w can be used with MTLS, as it has Websockets support.

However, the documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/evaluating-access-control-methods-to-secure-amazon-api-gateway-apis/) clearly says I cannot associate Websocket API with a domain that has MTLS enabled.

Can somebody help me understand:

- Why is MTLS not supported with AWS API G/w?
- Other than the obvious issue of provisioning each client with its own cert, are there other issues in using MTLS with Websockets?

My current working setup is:

- All clients are IoT devices and provisioned with client certificates
- Server is running in an AWS EKS cluster
- Server is configured with MTLS (server cert issued by ACM and server has been configured with CA cert to validate the client certs)
- Server uses NGINX Ingress controller in EKS for the MTLS setup
- Route53 and NLB configured for all of this to work
- The Server app uses Websockets for back and forth communication with the clients

This setup works. However, scaling the clients in this model has a direct dependency on the single EKS cluster and the region.

Trying to understand why AWS EKS would support MTLS+Websockets while API G/w won't (it individually has support for MTLS and Websockets, just not together!)